# Delete all Macros/vba when save as xls workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I am using a procedure that creates a file and copies my workbook (xlsm) and saves as a xls workbook to the created file, and this is working well.

I need to remove all Macros and vba when the **save as** is exacuted, i.e I need to remove the Macros/vba from the workbook being saved NOT the original workbook.

I know I could save it as a xlsx workbook to remove all Macros and vba but I need the workbook to be a Macro/vba free xls workbook.

I have Google'ed but did not find anything I could use, will continue to look and post back if I get this figured out.

Comment: I believe an easier solution is to have the macros in one workbook and the data in another.  It is easy for a macro to operate on another workbook.  Getting a macro to delete itself then save the workbook sounds more challenging.

Comment: It may be a bit of a hack, but I think it would be ultimately faster...why not save it as a .xlsx and then save the .xlsx as a .xls?  I know it's a two step process, but it would probably be easier than working through the steps here: http://www.cpearson.com/excel/vbe.aspx

Comment: You can always just export all the worksheets to a new workbook.  By default, none of the macros would be included in the new workbook.

Comment: Thanks everyone all good advice, I will for know use Cpearson coment as the most easy in the moment.  But in the long run Tony's and/or Stewbob's suggestions are good ones.

Comment: I would most likely take your approach, saving first to XLSM, closing and then reopening, and then saving to XLS. That to me seems the easiest, no hassle approach. You'd need another application or Excel file to orchestrate the solution.  But yes that's how I'd work it.

Comment: Doesn't saving as an xls or xlsx automatically remove the macros already?

Answer (score -1):

I found this here:

http://enholm.net/index.php/blog/vba-code-to-transfer-excel-2007-xlsx-books-to-2003-xls-format/

It searches through a dirictory looking for **xlsx** files and changes them to **xls** files

I think though it can be changed to look for **xlsm** files and change them to **xls** files as well.

When I run it I get:

```
Run-Time error '9' Subscript out of range

Debug
Sheets("List").Cells(r, 1) = Coll_Docs(i)
is highlighted in yellow
```

I do not know enough about vba to figure out what is not working.
Thanks

```
Sub SearchAndChange()
Dim Coll_Docs As New Collection

Dim Search_path, Search_Filter, Search_Fullname As String

Dim DocName As String

Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

Dim i As Long


Search_path = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\360 Compiled Repository\May_2013"

Search_Filter = "*.xlsx"

Set Coll_Docs = Nothing
DocName = dir(Search_path & "\" & Search_Filter)

 Do Until DocName = ""

    Coll_Docs.Add Item:=DocName

    DocName = dir

 Loop


 r = 1

 For i = Coll_Docs.Count To 1 Step -1

     Search_Fullname = Search_path & "\" & Coll_Docs(i)

     Sheets("List").Cells(r, 1) = Coll_Docs(i)

      Call changeFormats(Search_path, Coll_Docs(i))

      r = r + 1

Next

Application.DisplayAlerts = True

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

End Sub
'**************************************************************

'* Changes format from excel 2007 to 2003

'***************************************************************
Sub changeFormats(ByVal dir As String, ByVal fileName As String)

 Workbooks.Open fileName:=dir & fileName

 ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs fileName:=dir & Replace(fileName, "xlsx", "xls"),   FileFormat:=xlExcel8

ActiveWindow.Close
End Sub
```

Comment: Does `Sheets("List")` exists?

Comment: I feel deflated by my simple over sights, your insight was spot on.  Thank you!